# How do I get the user to input a word for string comparison?

Tags: c

I'm running a while loop so the user can constantly enter *expressions*, until they indicate they want to quit the program.  I'm using `strcmp()` to compare two strings so as soon as they enter `quit` the program will stop.  But the program keeps going, any Ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int min12=0;
    char opper;
    int x=0;
    int min13;
    char *Repeatprog="cont";
    char *Repeatprog1="quit";

    while (strcmp(Repeatprog,Repeatprog1))
    {
    printf("enter the integer number \n");
    scanf( "%d %c %d", &min12, &opper, &min13);
    printf("%d %c %d\n", min12, opper, min13);

    printf("Type the word quit to end program\n");
    scanf("%s", Repeatprog);
    }
    printf("Good Bye");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler say about this code?

Comment: What is `scanf("%c", &Repeatprog);` doing there? You just asked the user to type a word, not some character. And that code is wrong anyway. `%c` requires a `char*`, not a `char**`.

Comment: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%c", &Repeatprog);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score -1):

Remember always that an **Array** is a **Pointer** to the first object of the array.
And secondly, in your call to `scanf()` you only read a character. Not a whole string (represented by `%s` in C)

So in conclusion, your call to `scanf()` shouldn't have a pointer **and** should have a **string** instead of a **character**.

```
scanf("%s", Repeatprog);
```

or simply

```
gets (Repeatprog);
```

### EDIT :

As the commenter @EOF said, `gets()` is not a good idea since it can lead to `Undefined Behaviour`. That's because the program can read more characters than it should have and lead to overflow, thus it isn't secure.

So I recommend using `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`

### *Note:*

Also, your code is using string literals. So if you make any attempt to change the content of the `char` **pointer** then it will lead to `Undefined Behaviour`.

> **For this note, please thank the guys *below* me [comments]. I made a huge mistake and I'm sorry.**

Comment: `gets()` is not a C standard function any more, and for good reason. Recommending it gives an automatic `-1` from me. Also, undefined behavior for attempting to modify a string literal.

Comment: @EOF Yeah I suppose you're right. I should have recommended the fgets(). But by the time he doesn't even understand the Pointer and String/Character principle why should I do that...

Comment: @general656: The undefined behavior I mention is not limited to using `gets()`. It also happens when using the `scanf()`-variant or `fgets()`.

Comment: The `scanf()` was a reference to his code, not a recommendation of mine. So don't blame me for this one for no reason :) I Edited my post as you can see.

Comment: The problem is that `Repeatprog` as declared in the question cannot be used as an argument to `scanf`, `gets`, or `fgets`. To be correct, the answer needs to show the proper usage of the functions using properly declared variables.

Comment: Oh I'm so idiot. Hey user, thanks for clarifying this. I didn't see his whole code and I definately should. He initializes the strings ... I just show that.

Comment: @user3386109 Though, it's the same thing since `cont` and `quit` have the same length. So if he uses `fgets()` with a length of `4` he's fine.

Comment: @user3386109: *Technically*, string literals are *not* of type `const char *`, but of type `char []`. Nevertheless, modifying them is undefined behavior regardless of the lack of `const`. Welcome to C, beware the 40+ years of legacy.

Comment: @user3386109 EOF is right. You can write to them as long as it is the length of the initial string because char literal is just a typical initialized char array. 
If you think that now my answer has Full Content and it is as it should, you can upvote it. I did a 2nd edit now. If not then tell me what's still wrong. Thank you, EOF and user3386109.

Comment: @general656: **NO**. And don't put words in my mouth. Modifying a string literal is **not** allowed, as I pointed out in my *very first comment* on this (very incorrect) answer.

Comment: @EOF is correct, I have removed my comment. Here's what the C standard has to say, *"On the other hand, the declaration `char *p = "abc";`
defines `p` with type ‘‘pointer to char’’ and initializes it to point to an object with type ‘‘array of char’’ with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use `p` to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: Sorry I thought I tried it some time ago so I concluded that what you were saying was this. Didn't indent to Put words in your mouth. 
Now that we finally clarified this, I'll fix the whole thing. 

Sorry for the disturbance! You've been nice!